# JAVA "while" why does this code's result = 4949?

Tags: java

I think this code's result=4950.
That's because 99+98+...1=4950.
Would you please teach me how.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 100;
    int total = 0;
    while(n >= 0){
        total += --n;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Comment: what the output you are getting?

Comment: The key lesson for you to learn is how to debug problems like this as you would quickly see the cause of your result if you placed a println statement showing total and n *inside* the loop. Also learning to do this will pay you great dividends in the future.

Answer (score 13):

You are correct, 99+98+...+1=4950.  But you have to follow the logic.

Think about when n = 0.  The conditional of the while loop evaluates to true, and the decrement operator is applied before being added to `total`. If you decrement a variable that has a value of 0, you get -1, and when you add -1 to 4950, you get 4949.

So what we are really seeing is this:  99 + 98 + ... + 1 + 0 + (-1).  And that equals 4949.

Comment: Thank you nicholas.hauschild! I totally understand by your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the code like this:

```
System.out.println("before " + n + ", " + total);
total += --n;
System.out.println("after " + n + ", " + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a+=b means a=a+b;

a =--n means a = n-1 and n = n-1;   a=n-- means a=n;n=n-1;
```

so,in the loop:
first time:

```
total = total+99;//total = 0+99; n =99;
```

second time:

```
total = total+98;//total=99+98;n=98
```

....

at last ,you know...

Answer (score 1):

You decrement the value of n before adding it to total, with the last iteration adding -1 to the total.

Change the code to post-decrement to get the correct result adding 1..100; you'll need to change the start point to 99 if you want to add 1..99.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have put --n, the n value is getting reduced before it is added to the total. Since you have allowed the program to come inside the while loop when n is equal to 0 as well, the final adding is,

total += -1

Which means, 4950-1, so answer is 4949.

If you want to get 4950, change the condition in while loop as follows.

while(n > 0)

Then while loop does not allow the program to go inside the while loop if the value of n is equal to 0. Hence there is no -1 situation. You will get 4950.